How do exceptions work with the MMU in ARM Cortex A8 (ARMv7-A)?
Currently, I am studying the Cortex A8 kernel with MMU support. Previously, I only worked with Cortex M3, which did not have an MMU. According to the official documentation (ARM architecture reference manual), regular exceptions (IRQ, FIQ, Supervisor call, etc.) do not affect MMU settings. That is, in the section on exceptions, there is no mention of any impact on MMU settings.
From what I know, the MMU is used to ensure complete independence of executable processes. But then I don't understand how this can work. If the MMU is set up (by providing the necessary translation tables), the processor will start fetching and executing instructions at virtual addresses. But what happens if an exception occurs? Where will the processor look for the interrupt vector? At the virtual address (i.e., it will translate the virtual address to the physical address using the page tables) or directly at the physical address?
And what if the exception is an SVC (Supervisor Call)? For such an exception, the MMU tables must be switched somehow to transition to the kernel's virtual address space, but this does not happen automatically, as far as I understand.
Does this mean that the interrupt vector tables and the interrupt handlers themselves, which will change the MMU settings, must be mapped into the virtual address space of every process? But this contradicts the main principle of virtual address spaces – their complete independence. Moreover, based on this assumption, I did not find any code in the Linux kernel source (in the interrupt handlers) that changes the MMU settings. I'm confused.
Could you please explain what I am misunderstanding? If possible, with references to official documentation...
I tried looking in the source code of Linux interrupt handlers for any hints regarding MMU operations, but found nothing. Moreover, this issue is not discussed in the official documentation. It only mentions that there is an ASID field – an identifier for the process translation tables.
